# Problema al acceder a los elementos de un array ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

Que tal comunidad como verán soy nuevo en angularJs y tengo un problema al acceder a los elementos de un array.

aquí tengo mi controller

```
var app = angular.module("teApp")
.controller("NewPromotionDetailController", ['$window','$scope','$attrs','$http','$cookies', function($window, $scope, $attrs, $http, $cookies) {  
    var url = CQ.HTTP.noCaching(CQ.WCM.getDesign().getPath()+'/jcr:content/global.infinity.json');
    var items = CQ.HTTP.eval(url);
    $scope.sharedArray = items.compartirList;
    console.log(items.compartirList);
}]);
```

y la parte del HTML es donde falla al intentar acceder a un elemento del array.

```
<div ng-controller="NewPromotionDetailController">
   <div ng-repeat="item in sharedArray">
          <p>{{item}}</p>
          <a href=""><img ng-src="{{item.iconoCompartir}}"/></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

como si accedo como tal solo {{item}} lo hace bien trae consigo cada elemento dentro del arreglo pero si intento acceder a un dato en particular dentro de cada elemento no me trae nada es decir {{item.foo}} ya me asegure que ese dato si existe en el arreglo.

De esta forma viene la variable items.compartirList que es la que tengo en el scope por lo que no hay problema con ella

```
[{"iconoCompartir":"/content/dam/tecom/iconos/icon-fb.png","tipoCompartir":"external","enlaceCompartir":"https://www.facebook.com/","noFollowCompartir":["true"]},  
{"iconoCompartir":"/content/dam/tecom/iconos/icon-tw.png","tipoCompartir":"internal","enlaceCompartir":"https://twitter.com/login?lang=es","noFollowCompartir":[]}]
```

Comment: si creas una variable $scope.IconoCompartir = items.compartirList.iconoCompartir; y lo llamas en tu html {{ IconoCompartir }} creo que debería funcionarte si es lo que estas buscando.

Comment: si funciona sin embargo compartirList tiene otros objetos que tambien me interesa obtenerlos al mismo tiempo por lo que lo ideal seria obtenerlos con un ng -repeat y el scope a compartirList

Comment: lograste alguna conclusión?

Comment: Si lo siento no había podido responder antes, coloque una posible solución sin embargo no estoy 100% si sea problema con que angularjs o se me paso algo.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno regreso después de una semana ya que había estado muy ocupado y no pude responder antes.

El problema parece ser que angular no me reconoce la estructura del jsonArray por lo que no puede acceder a sus elementos, como el problema se debía de resolver rápido opte por guardar los elementos en un array y posteriormente pasar ese array de esta manera el ng-repeat ya no estaria tratando de leer un jsonData si no un Array directamente

```
            var app = angular.module("teApp")
        .controller("NewPromotionDetailController", ['$window','$scope','$attrs','$http','$cookies', function($window, $scope, $attrs, $http, $cookies) {
               var array = [];
               var url = CQ.HTTP.noCaching(CQ.WCM.getDesign().getPath()+'/jcr:content/global.infinity.json');
               var items = CQ.HTTP.eval(url);
               var jsonData = items;
               for(var i=0; i < jsonData.compartirList.length; i++ ){
                 array.push(JSON.parse(jsonData.compartirList[i]))
               }
               $scope.sharedArray = array;

        }]);
```

Es algo raro por que la estructura del json cumple con el estándar y de hecho pude acceder a sus datos con un simple for.

Como mencione estoy un poco cargado de trabajo por lo que no pude aunar mucho en el tema si alguno de ustedes puede aportar algo mas al problema se los agradeceré